# JSON value in one cell export in another cell

Tags: json, google-sheets

I need some help regarding Google Sheets. I'm working on some game data and all the stats are in a JSON structure in a cell. I want to export it base on the variables I need to get.

Please see link here for sample input and output.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XyCC_0h5JvVOHvtW5Xh5ng4ZSHgmCQJ1D2PAL2zkgIM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***updated formula***:

```
=index(let(
           a,transpose(trim(split(A2,char(10)))),
           b,query(a,"offset 1"),
textjoin(char(10),1,ifna(byrow(a,lambda(z,ifna(regexextract(z,"key.*""(.*)"""))))&": "&byrow(b,lambda(z,regexextract(z,"value.*""(.*)""")))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I just did a test. It seems some of the values comes out blank :( Updated the sheet though with the data.

Comment: updated formula in the answer. please do test it out.

Comment: Thank you! Your formula made me look them up. Sorry took some time. Trying to understand. 

You rock, @rockinfreakshow